# Расставить знаки препинания в предложении с прямой речью

Tags: пунктуация, прямая-речь

Как правильно расставить знаки препинания в предложении?

> И спросил у него старец, ты много жизней прожил, скажи мне, зачем я нужен?

Answer (score 0):

> И спросил у него старец: «Ты много *жизней* прожил. Скажи мне, зачем я нужен?»

> И спросил у него старец: «Ты много *жизней* прожил. Скажи мне: зачем я нужен?»

Вот так надо, мэм. Выбирайте. Во втором пауза — из-за двоеточия — длиннее. Я не люблю соединять предложение вопросительное и предложение утвердительное просто посредством запятой.